# Are there any benefits of adding attention to linear layers?

Tags: neural-networks, pytorch, attention, dense-layers

Is attention useful only in transformer/convolution layers? Can I add it to linear layers? If yes, how (on a conceptual level, not necessarily the code to implement the layers)?